# How to make unique urls in django with url-pattern that uses multiple parameters?

Tags: django, url-pattern

My url is structured in this way:

example.com/category/subcategory/name

Right now I'm using a DetailView and it detects the url when I write it but it resolves positively to any address that includes the right name because that name is unique so what I need to check is that the name corresponds to the subcategory and this subcategory corresponds to the main category.

For example my desired url is:

http://example.com/animal/cat/garfield

It resolves alright with a 200 code.
However, when I write:

http://example.com/insect/cat/garfield

It also resolves as a 200 instead of a 404.

How do I check those parameters in my view?

My urls.py

```
path('<str:category>/<str:subcategory>/<str:slug>', views.AnimalDetailView.as_view(), name="animal_detail")
```

My view:

```
class AnimalDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Animal

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['now'] = timezone.now()
        return context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is that, in `get_object` method, put the constrain yourself by overriding it. For example:

```
class AnimalDetailView(DetailView):
     ...
     def get_object(self):
         category = self.kwargs.get('category')
         subcategory = self.kwargs.get('subcategory')
         slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
         animal = Animal.objects.filter(category=category, subcategory=subcategory, slug=slug)
         if animal.exists():
              return super(AnimalDetailView, self).get_object()
         else: 
              Http404("Animal not found")
```

Comment: It's throwing a ValueError, it tries to compare the word with an int value.

Comment: writing category__slug it seems to work but when it doesn't find anything it still gets an object so it never throws a 404, rather an empty view.

Comment: means you have an Animal object for /insect/cat/garfield somewhere. Can you share your Category, SubCategory and Animal Model please?

Answer (score 0):

I think your URL should end with a `/`. Refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/

```
path('<str:category>/<str:subcategory>/<str:slug>/', views.AnimalDetailView.as_view(), name="animal_detail").
```

All parameters passed through URL will get using kwargs. If you want access parameters in your view you can use the following approaches
1)

```
class Test(DetailView):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        subcategory = kwargs['subcategory']
        category = kwargs['category']
```

2)

```
class Test(DetailView):
    def get(self, request, category, subcategory, .. ):
        # category contains value of category
```

The first method is preferred approach.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not my question.

Comment: Could you post full URLs.py.  Because everything looks fine and it should work!

Comment: What I want is to be able to process all the three url parameters in that generic view to have only one valid url.